# How to design a JK latch

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, schematics, flipflop, latch

I am trying to simulate a JK latch in a circuit builder. What I have come up with thus far is the following:

[image]

I don't have control of the wiring (the application automatically does these wirings, often convoluted or hard to read), and so I'm having a bit of trouble debugging the circuit to see what is wrong. Additionally, the app doesn't support a three input AND gate, so I'm using 2 AND gates to simulate that, for example:

[image]

Regardless of what logic input I change, the output does not ever change. What seems to be wrong with my circuit here?

Additionally, here's an example using Logicly where I get something very similar: https://gyazo.com/6d594c52b21e2c4208dc6872ca1a9e8d.

[image]

Comment: Remove the two AND gates on the left and see if it works. Label your inputs and gates. Otherwise discussion gets very difficult. Provide a link to the application and your simulation, if possible. Alternatively find a better simulator.

Comment: @Transistor what simulator would you recommend? This simulator (everycircuit) doesn't allow you to label anything.

Comment: Does Falstad do logic? If you have a Java-enabled browser you can try https://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/index.html.

Comment: @Transistor yes it works without the 3-and (as a normal sr latch with enable)

Comment: https://logic.ly/ seems OK too.

Comment: I'd recommend [Neemann's Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital). It's well-maintained (updates seem to be about monthly) and works very well. And it supports a gate-level propagation step mode, which can be helpful for circuits like this (the JK FF.) You could check it out. It will simulate the master-slave JK without any difficulties. But the gate-level propagation step mode will be preferred for the simpler JK FF, if you want to see it oscillate when both inputs are "1" and you clock it.

Comment: @Transistor I've tried this but I also run into the same issue with logic.ly. Here's a video: https://gyazo.com/6d594c52b21e2c4208dc6872ca1a9e8d

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help further. I see you've accepted an answer below so I take it that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feedback from each NOR gate should go back to the AND gate on the same side. Also the flip flop needs to be triggered with a very narrow clock pulse.

[image: JK Flip Flop]

[image: JK Flip Flop]

Master-Slave flipflops for completeness

[image: Master-Slave flipflops]

Comment: like this? https://imgur.com/a/0Pk5M8x It seems like the feedback from the Q/Q_ is just always zero for me.

Comment: With feedback both at zero, the two inputs into the NORs are both zero which means that one of the NOR outputs must be at 1.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by that? If one of them is on, why isn't the lightbulb turned on?

Comment: I see now, thanks for this, I was doing the feedback diagonally, which it is not for the Nor gates as opposed to the Nand.

Comment: Could you please add a link or citation for the graphics you included in your answer? We always want to give credit to the original creator of material like this.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson I created the graphics myself, including the tables, a while ago using Circuit Wizard and Paint. But thanks, credit accepted.  ;-)

Comment: You deserve the credit, those are nice graphics.

Answer (score 0):

a JK flip-flop can be built using two latch layers and two gate layers.

[image]